# How to multiply/divide one function to another ? How to use parameters?

Tags: c++, parameters, calling-convention

How do I multiply a function to another function? and how do I properly use parameters?

I'm not exactly sure, I am really new to C++ with only about 14 weeks of class time.

Something I've tried would be creating a new function meant to multiply other functions and in the arguments I would put in the functions names.

For example:

```
float mealMath(numberOfAdults, mealChoosing){
   //Rest of function
}
```

but I always get an error.Please explain how to fix this, this is a big obstacle in programming for me and I can't seem to grasp how to fix this or go about doing these things. Don't be to harsh on me for this.Thanks!

```
int numberOfAdults(){
    int totalAdults;
            cout << "Now how many adults will there be?: ";
            cin >> totalAdults;
                cout << "It seems there will be: " <<                      totalAdults << " Adults." << endl;
                    while(totalAdults < 1){
                        cout << "Sorry there has to be a minimum of 1 adult!" << endl;
                            cout << "How many adults: "; 
                                cin >>  totalAdults;
                    }
                    return 0;
}

int numberOfKids(){
    int totalKids;
        cout << "Now how many Kids will there be?: ";
            cin >> totalKids;
                cout << "It seems there will be: " <<   totalKids << " kids." << endl;
                    while(totalKids < 0){
                        cout << "Sorry there has   to be a minimum of 1 Kid!" << endl;
                            cout << "How many   Kids: "; 
                            cin >>   totalKids;
                    }
                    return 0;
                  }


float mealChoosing(){
    float cost;
        string mealChoise;
            cout << "   " << endl;
                cout << "Now, What meal will you be    getting(D/S): ";
                    cin >> mealChoise;
                        if(mealChoise == "D"){
                            cout << "It seems you have selected the Deluxe Meal plan for everyone!" << endl;
                                cost = 25.95;
                        }
                                    if(mealChoise == "S"){
                                        cout << "It seems you have selected the Standard Meal plan for everyone!" <<     endl;
                                            cost = 21.75;
                            }
                                                cout << "   " << endl;

                                                return cost;
}
```

One expected result is I want to multiply the input that the user gives in function "numberOfAdults" to the input a user gives for "mealChoosing"

So I want numberOfAdults * mealChoosing but I want that done in a different function so

```
"float total(){
   float totalBill;
     totalBill = numberOfAdults * mealChoosing;
       cout << totalBill;"
```

or something along those lines. I can't complete this project because I can't for some reason properly give the functions the proper information needed in parameters.

Comment: Note that your functions `numberOfAdults` and `numberOfKids` will *always* return `0`.

Comment: Your indentation is kind of weird as well, making it very hard to read those functions.

Comment: Lastly, you don't divide or multiply functions, you divide and multiply the *result* of the functions, the values that they *return*. Perhaps you should refresh how to call functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case(and most) you should not declare a function whose parameters are functions. Instead declare mealMath with an integer and a float input:

```
float mealMath(int a, float b){/*Your code here*/}
```

And then later call mealMath with the other two functions passed as arguments.

```
float x = mealMath(numberOfAdults(), mealChoosing());
```

Alternatively you can have no function parameters for `mealMath()` and instead call `numberOfAdults()` and `mealChoosing()` from inside of the function.

It's important to note that most of the time you'll be calling a function and using its output as an argument, and therefore you'll need to put the `()` after the function's identifier, instead of just typing the identifier alone.

Comment: okay so im not gonna lie im pretty lost, how can I give two integer inputs to mealMath and then it seems to change and go to the other functions? and where do I call "float x = mealMath(numberOfAdults(), mealChoosing())" in the program? it just seems confusing and I feel like its easier than im making it out to be in my head

Comment: To first address your first question: you have functions that output float/int values, so when you pass a function into the function arguments, it will take the outputted float/int value of the passed function. Second, you can call `float x = mealMath(numberOfAdults(), mealChoosing());` anywhere, in any function, _after_ it has been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Like `mealChoosing()` return `totalAdults` and `totalKids` (although its not needed here) from  `numberOfAdults()`, `numberOfKids()` respectively.

```
int numberOfAdults() {
  //...
  return totalAdults;
}

int numberOfKids() {
    //..
    return totalKids;
}

float mealChoosing() {
 //..

  return cost;
}
```

Now on  `mealMath(numberOfAdults, mealChoosing)`

```
float mealMathOutput = mealMath(numberOfAdults(), mealChoosing());
```